# Encoding numbers in RLE Compression

Tags: algorithm, rle

I am working on implementing dynamic version of **RLE** compression.

On this version I only insert characters count in the **RLE Code** if it's more than 1, other than that I keep it as its original state.

The problem I encounter here when trying to encode numbers in the original input text.

Is there any way to encode them like alphabet characters without losing efficiency of the RLE **compression ratio**.

**Example**

```
text = "aabccc 123 ghe dd12 Goooooal"
```

I want to encode it like:

```
2ab3c 123 ghe 2d12 G5oal
```

But I need some kind of encoding for `123` and `12` in RLE code.

Comment: You could use some special character to separate the number from the character then repeat anything you need to escape "1" times.

Comment: If your alphabet is 7 bits ASCII, all the extended values are free for use.

Comment: You need an escape character to distinguish between your repeat-number and numbers in the original text. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Comment: @MrSmith42 so the RLE code with escape character will be now look like: `2ab3c \1\2\3 ghe 2d\1\2 G5oal`.

Comment: @MrSmith42 In this case it will be inefficient approach because it will increase number of characters by 1 for each escape character of the digit.

Comment: @mousetail It could work but in this case you should distinguish between special character in RLE code and input or remove this special character from the input.

Comment: @Oghli No, you can easily escape them by repeating them 1ce

Comment: @mousetail yes it could work. but there are some cases when this special character repeated specific number times in input text.

Comment: Super easy then. Repeat them some other number of times then 1 in those cases

Comment: @mousetail in this case it will be inefficient because it increases number of encoding characters in RLE code -> meaning more size.

Comment: No it will be exactly as efficient as without escaping in those cases. Only when they are repeated once will it increase the size.

Comment: `2ab3c \1\2\3 ghe 2d\1\2 G5oal. ` is the naive and maybe not space efficient version to escape it. You could also  instead escape your count-values instead `\2ab\3c 123 ghe \2d12 G\5oal. ` This way you could decide only to encode repetitions of at least 4 to ensure that your encoding actually compresses the String. `aabccc 123 ghe dd12 G\5oal. `

Comment: Perhaps the encoded version might be `2ab3c \123\ ghe 2d\12\ G5oa` where the first instance of `\\` shifts into numeric mode, the next instance unshifts, etc.  Whether this presents an unacceptable increase in the length of the encoded string depends on how many numbers there are in the original string, and how long they are.  I think this may be what @mousetail originally proposed.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark yes I think this approach may work in my case. I don't think that what mousetail suggested in his comment.